# samba library failed to download the shared files of Mac osx

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, samba, smb

I have tried to download the shared files of mac osx using smb from my ipad but it fails with error( unable to open the file). But it can download all windows and linux shared files.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by updating version of samba static library in ios.